# How to create a draggable menu div (desktop and mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How to make the above? 
It can drag up and down by dragging the menu text area (menu image or some inner div), and the div comes down or up (with max and min limits) as its dragged.

I cant make this code working, can any one give a practical code?

```
whole_menu.onPress = function() {
startDrag(this);
};
whole_menu.onRelease =function () {
stopDrag();
};


whole_menu.onPress = function() {
startDrag(this, false, 0, this._y, 800-this._width, this._y);
};
whole_menu.onRelease =function () {
stopDrag();
};
```

**EDIT:**
added more explanation and code, so 
**no need to close this question**

Comment: wishing someone at your service? what you have done so far?

Comment: the code is there, I just thought its stupid

Comment: just to warn you, it's totally unusual (yet in 2013) talking about User Xperience to drag menus down to reveal content. Just out of curiosity, why you need that feature? it's for mobile, right?

Comment: @roXon yes. I want to implement the same style as mobiles do. many androids. its just a matter of desire (making new trends)

Comment: you're using http://jquerymobile.com/ ? no, for mobile is perfect! I like it, but not for desktop machines. that was my only concern.

Comment: I want the site to work on all OS. not just mobile. and in the same way

Comment: let me try to setup a code. I did something similar in the past: http://roxon.in/scripts/vertiscroll/

Comment: @roXon Man, your scroll bars are really  nice. but not working offline on a saved page

Comment: @roXon I couldn't resist it. But I also voted to close, as I didn't think anyone would have the kindness to post a complete solution as you did (voted from `/review`, couldn't see your answer!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(**Without jQuery UI**) I build this, should work on all mobile devices! (Tested also on mobile - Android)

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/caqupon/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

```js
var $MB = $('#menu_btn'),
    $M = $('#menu'),
    $DOM = $(document),
    startAtY = 10, // CSS px
    endAtY = 270,  // CSS #menu height px
    clickedAtY,
    clickEventType= document.ontouchstart !== null ? 'mousedown' : 'touchstart',
    moveEventType = document.ontouchmove  !== null ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove' ,
    endEventType  = document.ontouchend   !== null ? 'mouseup'   : 'touchend'  ;

$MB.on(clickEventType, function( e ) { 

  e.preventDefault();  

  clickedAtY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  if(clickEventType === 'touchstart'){
    clickedAtY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  }
  
  $DOM.on(moveEventType, moveHandler)
      .on(endEventType, stopHandler);

});

function moveHandler( e ) {
  var posY = e.pageY - clickedAtY;
  if(moveEventType === 'touchmove') {
    posY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY - clickedAtY;
  }
  posY = Math.min( Math.max(0, posY), endAtY - startAtY);
  $M.css({top: posY});
}

function stopHandler() {
  $DOM.off(moveEventType, moveHandler)
      .off(endEventType,  stopHandler);
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

body{font-family:Arial;}

#menu_wrapper{
  height:0px;
}
#menu{
  background:#444;
  height:280px;
  margin-top:-270px;
  color:#ccc;
  position:relative;
}
#menu_btn{
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#444;
  padding:10px 20px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
    left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_wrapper">
  <div id="menu">

    <div id="menu_btn">DRAG ME DOWN</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds

Comment: ok. why the scroll (auto by mouse movement) dont work if i save your site page as complete webpage despite.

Comment: @Masood make sure to wrap all the jQ code into *Document Ready* : `$(function(){ /*CODE HERE*/ });`